# Using nullable bool in HTML helper in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. I need to create an HTML helper to generate a custom Checkbox field. I have the Checkbox field working with `bool` values. However, I'm not sure how to do it with nullable bool values (`bool?`). Currently, I have the following extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CreateCheckbox<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, bool?>> expression, string classes = " ")
{
  var str = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.CheckBoxFor(html, expression).ToString();
  var s= ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
  var html = string.Format("<label for=\"{0}\">{1}&nbsp;{2}</label>", s.PropertyName, str, s.GetDisplayName());
  return new MvcHtmlString(html);
}
```

When I compile it, I get the following error:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,bool?>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,bool>>'
```

How can I accept nullable bool values in this HTML helper?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.yourNullableBool)` - it generates a dropdown with 3 values, "True", "False" and "Not Set", where "Not Set" equates to `null` when you post back. You cant use a checkbox to represent a nullable bool because a checkbox has only 2 states where as a nullable bool has 3 states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 defines a property for checkboxes called *indeterminate*. Unfortunately, it cannot be set with markup, only with JavaScript. And it doesn't change the value of checkbox, it's just a visual thing. Not all of the browsers have support for them. I'd highly encourage to use dropdown list for that case. So the user won't be intimidated by third-party custom checkboxes with 3 states. Moreover, dropdown list will work on all devices and browsers.